# Android- Cardview with round corners containing a round progressbar within

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

Right now what I am trying to achieve is a cardview with round corners which contains a progressbar within.

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/upperLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="21dp"
        app:cardElevation="17dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.012"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

        <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            app:pv_autostart="true"
            app:pv_circular="true"
            app:pv_progressMode="indeterminate"
            app:pv_progressStyle="@style/Material.Drawable.CircularProgress" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In my design view everything looks good:
[image: Android Studio Design View]

But in my emulator:
[image: Emulator]

Everything works fine with `api >21` but right now my `minSdk is 19`, so both my emulator and my design view have `api 19` set.

Any ideas/ suggestions?

Comment: The problem is that padding is different pre-lollipop than API 21+. Enable [`cardUseCompatPadding`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html#attr_CardView_cardUseCompatPadding) on your `CardView` and you'll see the same thing in your design view (the bad one).

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy , ok well then any ideas on how should I approach this? Is there any way pre-lollipop to achieve this? Or at least something similar. I want a progressbar within a cardview in order to have that elevation over other elements in the layout.

Comment: Did you try setting `app:contentPadding="0dp"` on your `CardView`?

Comment: yes I tried, but in vain. I ended up making a circular shape for a LinearLayout to get the same result.